How to make right deduction of c++ template argument
It is found that when template arguments are a combination of type and non-type template arguments, the compiler cannot make a right deduction when the template is specialized.
Take below code as example, suppose tmpl_vs in main has two arguments: sa and 1, however, compiler takes it as 0.  Is there a way to resolve this?

#include <stdio.h>

struct sa {};
struct sb {};

/// tmpl_vs has sevaral different classes as arguments, just use 1 here as example.
template <class a_type, int VS>
struct tmpl_vs
{
  static_assert(sizeof(a_type) == 0, "Unexpected.");
};

template <int vs>
struct tmpl_vs<sa, vs> {
  void func() { printf("tmpl_vs<sa,vs>\n"); }
};

template <int vs>
struct tmpl_vs<sb, vs> {
  void func() { printf("tmpl_vs<sb,vs>\n"); }
};

template<class... Args>
void
tmpl_func(tmpl_vs<Args...> &) {
  printf("1\n");
}

template<class... Args, int... I>
void
tmpl_func(tmpl_vs<Args..., I...> &) {
  printf("2\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argvp[]) {
  tmpl_vs<sa, 1> a;
  tmpl_func(a);
  return 0;
}

Expected result: Make compilation pass, and print "2".

If you replace the variadic parameter pack Args with a single template  parameter T, the code works as expected. Do you really need an arbitrary number of types?

there is another simple fix https://godbolt.org/z/b8dYEedoq

Yes, need arbitrary number of types, as mentioned in code comments, it has sevaral different types as arguments, and I just want some take this speicalization, which print "2".


suppose tmpl_vs in main has two arguments: sa and 1, however, compiler takes it as 0. Is there a way to resolve ?

Just change the parameter packs to normal template parameters as shown below. Note also that the primary template tmpl_vs takes exactly two template argument(first type and second non-type).
//-------------vvvv------v---> not parameter packs
template<class Args, int I>
//---------------------vvvv--v------->No pack expansion
void tmpl_func(tmpl_vs<Args, I> &) {
  printf("2\n");
}


int main(int argc, char* argvp[]) {
  tmpl_vs<sa, 1> a;
  tmpl_func(a);
  return 0;
}


Working demo

Note that you can also use auto& as function parameter but then the function will accept any type of argument. You can then restrict it using different techniques but the simplest is to just not use the parameter packs(as primary template tmpl_vs has exactly two parameters) as shown in the first part of the ansswer.

Thanks for the demo.  It works when template arguments is not so many, as we can enumerate one by one. But as mentioned in code comments, there are sevaral different types as arguments, like the 10 in list. So I suppose it not feasible in reality.

@shdetect I see, that is why I always ask for a real [mcve]. Other option is voidtmpl_func(auto &) {printf("2\n");}. See demo as mentioned at the end of the answer.
